# How to operate on each individual rendered element when they are mapped from object array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a shopping app which repeats the same card. Instead of manually rendering them, I used `map` to render array objects like this:

Parent component:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: tshirt,
      price: 10
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: hat,
      price: 20
    }
  ]
  
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
  const itemNo = 2;
  
  const handleClick = (price) => {
     setTotalPrice(price * itemNo);
  }
  
  const RenderCards = () => {
    return (
      dummyData.map(
        (d) => 
          <Card key={d.id} title={d.title} price={d.price} totalPrice={totalPrice}/>
      )
    )
  }
  
  return(
    <>
      <RenderCards />
    </>
  )
}
```

and the child component:

```js
const Card = (id, title, price, totalPrice) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p>{totalPrice}</p>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick(price)}>Click for total price</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

When clicking the button on each card, I'd like to display total price for each card, i.e. for card 1, total price should be 10 * 2 = 20, and for card 2 should be 40. Clicking card 1 should only change {totalPrice} of card 1, card 2 should not be affected, vice versa.

However what I have so far is when clicking the button, both card would show the same total price. I understand this behaviour as the same data is passed to the card component, but how can I individually set data for each card in this case when components are rendered from array map?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of what you intend. Should the button click display a new "total price" for each card, or just change the price shown on that one card?

Comment: You need an object in your state like this: { { id:1, qty: 5}, { id:2, qty:10} }. In your setTotalPrice, you need to pass the existing state and the new qty for this product. In your map totalPrice = price * qty. HandleClick should have id and qty (total or to add).

Comment: @RobinZigmond just change the total price in each card, say clicking card 1 button, only card 1 {tootalPrice} should change to 20. Card 2 should do nothing.

Comment: @JB_DELR can you provide an elaborated answer please?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu, done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Home = () => {
  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: tshirt,
      price: 10
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: hat,
      price: 20
    }
  ]
  
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState([]); //<-- an empty array for start

  
  const handleClick = (id, qty) => {
     let newState = [...totalPrice]; //<--- copy the state
     if (newState.find(item => item.id === id) != undefined) { // find the item to add qty, if not exists, add one
       newState.find(item => item.id === id).qty += qty
     } else {
       newState.push({id:id, qty:qty});
     }
     setTotalPrice(newState); //<-- set the new state
  }
  
  const RenderCards = () => {
    return (
      dummyData.map(
            (d) => {
               const stateItem = totalPrice.find(item=> item.id === d.id); // return the item or undefined
               const qty = stateItem ? stateItem.qty : 0 // retreive qty from state by id or 0 if the product is not in the array
               return (
                 <Card key={d.id} title={d.title} price={d.price} totalPrice={d.price * qty}/>  //calculate the total    
               )
            }
      )
    )
  }
  
  return(
    <>
      <RenderCards />
    </>
  )
}
```

and card:

```
const Card = (id, title, price, totalPrice) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p>{totalPrice}</p>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick(id, 1)}>Click for add one</button>  // add one, total price will be good on the next render
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

maybe buggy but the idea is here

Comment: You can rename totalPrice and setTotalPrice to cartList and setCartList for example

Comment: So your state looks like this [ { id:1, qty: 5}, { id:2, qty:10} ]

Comment: tried it and gave me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'qty' of undefined` error on line `const qty = totalPrice.find(item => item === d.id).qty`

Comment: The array is empty, so need to check like in handleClick